# Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.2.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

```js
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java application project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the 'Building Java & JVM projects' chapter in the Gradle
 * User Manual available at https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/building_java_projects.html
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application in Java.
    id 'application'
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false

}

repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }

}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0-rc02'

    // Use JUnit Jupiter for testing.
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.9.0'

    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:31.1-jre'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass = 'hello.App'
}

android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    compileSdk 33
    buildToolsVersion '33.0.0'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    // Use JUnit Platform for unit tests.
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I want to build my project in Android Studio.

This is the error I get when I sync my project with gradle files. [I'm wondering if this is not causing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bGAT.jpg)files:

Gradle sync failed: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.2.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:
- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.2.2')
Searched in the following repositories:
Gradle Central Plugin Repository (1 s 312 ms)

Comment: Can you add graddle app build file here.?

Comment: I've added it as per above!

Comment: id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false change this to  id 'com.android.application' and check whether it work?

Comment: I tried it. It gives me the same error

Comment: This is what is gives me now:Gradle sync failed: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application'] was not found in any of the following sources:

Comment: Does the below answer worked?

Comment: No it doesn't, I get the same error, I'm on the latest version of gradle (7.5.1)

Comment: I fixed my problem, removed include('app') from settings.gradle file, sync project with gradle files and it worked. All that was left in that file was these two lines: rootProject.name = 'Hello'
rootProject.buildFileName = 'build.gradle.kts'